# How to receive a function parameter of any type in C++ and get the type of the passed variable inside the function?

Tags: c++

I want to be able to receive any type for the argument of a function and inside the function to determine the given type and take action accordingly.

Pseudocode:

```
void myFunction(any argument)
{
   if(argument is int)
   {
      myFunctionInt(argument);
   }
   if(argument is string)
   {
      myFunctionString(argument);
   }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: One solution would be template for the outer function (`myFunction`) and overloading for the called functions (`myFunctionInt` and `myFunctionString`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all you should take a look at simple function overloading which allows you to achieve that it in an oldschool fassion:

```
void my_function(int value) {
    std::cout << "int\n";
}

void my_function(std::string value) {
    std::cout << "string\n";
}
```

Though this has some downsides, as it takes quite some lines of code (a new function for each type!). You also need to specifically name the type (with all qualifiers), which may be undesirable.

---

To follow your pseudecode, when using C++17 you can use [`if-constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) to choose the right branch at compile time.

This is great, because you are even allowed to say something like `value.length()` when inside the `std::string` branch! This isn't possible with an regular old `if`.

So how can you determine what type `value` is? [`std::is_same_v<T, U>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) allows to perform an comparison, yielding only `true` if `T` is exactly an `U` - `int` or `std::string` in this case:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void my_function(T value) {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>) {
        std::cout << "int\n";
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::string>) {
        std::cout << "string\n";
    }
}
```

This is how it performs:

```
my_function(5); //-> prints out 'int'
my_function(std::string{ "hello" }); //-> prints out 'string'
```

However, `std::is_same_v` doesn't consider qualifiers. This is a problem, for example this won't print out anything:

```
my_function<const int>(5);
```

because `const int` is not the same as `int`. To get rid of `const` and any references `&` [`std::decay_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) comes in handy:

```
template<typename T>
void my_function(T value) {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, int>) {
        std::cout << "int\n";
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, std::string>) {
        std::cout << "string\n";
    }
}
```

which correctly works, as seen now:

```
my_function<const int>(5);
my_function<const std::string&>(std::string{ "hello" });
```

> ```
> int
> string
> ```

Comment: Prefer overloads to template function specialization. See http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm

Answer (score 2):

Well there's a pretty cool thing in cpp called [template functions](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/templates/)

e.g

```
template <typename T>
void tempFunction(T param){...}
```

and for your question to check the type, you can use [is_same](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) from type_traits library to compare the type

e.g

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
void tempFunction(T param) {
    if (std::is_same<T, std::string>::value)
        std::cout << "string" << std::endl;
    else if (std::is_same<T, int>::value)
        std::cout << "int" << std::endl;
    //...
}
```

and here's how you'd use it

```
int main(void) {
    int a = 10;
    std::string str = "Moo";
    std::string str2 = "Moo";
    tempFunction(str);
    tempFunction(a);
    tempFunction(str2);
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output:

```
string
int
string
```

Answer (score 1):

Template the function and make overloads for the recessary types.

```
template <typename T>

void myFunction(T a){

     myFunction(a);    
}

void myFunction(int i)
{
}

void myFunction(std::string)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a template

```
template <typename T>
void myFunction(T param);
```

And specialise it for certain types

```
template <>
void myFunction<int>(int param)
{
    // int things here
}

template <>
void myFunction<std::string>(std::string param)
{
    // string things here
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Templates are a big option.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/extensions/generics-and-templates-visual-cpp?view=vs-2019

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
void myFunction(T argument) {

    cout << typeid(argument).name() << endl;

    if (typeid(argument) == typeid(char)) {
        cout << "some stuff on char" << endl;
    }else if (typeid(argument) == typeid(int)) {
        cout << "some stuff on int" << endl;
    }else if (typeid(argument) == typeid(const char*)) {
        cout << "some stuff on string" << endl;
    }


}

int main()
{
    myFunction('s');

    myFunction(10);

    myFunction("smoker hehe");

    cout << "Great example by deon cagadoes\n"; 
    system("pause");
}
```